# Upgrading crm 4 plugins project from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, dynamics-crm-4

I have a visual studio 2005 class library project with the plugins for a microsoft crm 4 installation. I want to upgrade the project to visual studio 2010 but I still have to use the `.net 2.0` platform.

I tried to convert using the VS2010 wizard and the project is successfully converted but when I try to build I get several errors related to the references.

One is related to the `System.Serialization.Runtime`that in VS2010 I can't find using the `.net 2.0` framework.

Another problem is related to the assembly`microsoft.crm.sdk`. I'm getting the following message:

> The primary reference "microsoft.crm.sdk, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=x86" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the framework assembly
>   "System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve
>   this problem, either remove the reference "microsoft.crm.sdk,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=x86" or retarget your application to a framework
>   version which contains "System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

The message refers that `microsoft.crm.sdk` version is 4.0.0.0 which is not correct, it should be 2.0.0.0. Maybe there is something that is confusing VS2010 here.

I tried to remove the assemblies and put them back again (`System.Serialization.Runtime` I couldn't even put it back again because it doesn't show on the list of the .Net references), it didn't work.

Also, tried changing the `.net` framework to version 4.0 and back again to `.net 2.0`. Didn't work also, although while in 4.0 it successfully built.
I even tried going to VS2008 and then to VS2010. Converting to VS2008 I had no problem but when I got to VS2010 again I had the same problems.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this?

Comment: Have you changed Target Platform to .Net 2.0 in properties of project?

Comment: When it converted it maintained the .net 2.0 target. And like I said, I changed it to .net 4.0 and then again to .net 2.0 to see if that would solve anything but with no avail.

Comment: I don't suppose the downvoter would care to explain what's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target .NET framework 3.0

> Any .NET assembly that is created with Visual Studio .NET 2005 or 2008
>   and the **.NET Framework version 3.0** for use in Microsoft Dynamics
>   CRM as a Microsoft Dynamics CRM plug-in assembly or as a Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM custom workflow activity is supported.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928223.aspx)

Comment: Although it doesn't answer my question completely I am going to accept it. If in VS 2005 I target .net 2.0, when I change to other VS version it should be ok if I am targeting at least to the same .net framework. I don't know why but I was convinced that I had to target .net 2.0. I think that is in CRM 3.0. There's already to many CRM versions in my head :)